# How to detect if mouse is over an item in jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Is it possible to check if the cursor is over an item? In my case I can't use focus(), mouseenter() or any of the related methods but I just need to find out if the mouse is over it.

Comment: You can't use it... Why exactly?

Comment: I meant hover(), not focus().

Comment: The item gets partially covered and therefore mouseout is not detected so I want to force the item to be removed when the mouse is not over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the state of the mouse, in this particular case you could create a transparent overlay element on top of the one you want to hide.

So as that when the area is hovered it shows and when it's not it gets hidden
**obviously setting the element that is to be hidden (until hovered) with a default 
display: none; in your css** - therefore it only shows when hovered, to the users eye.

I know it's not what the OP was asking for but it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* 
    * #object is your element you 
    * want to hide unless hovered
    */
    $("#object").on("mouseleave", function(){
        // divs you want to hide/show
        $('#object').hide();
        $('#overlay').show();
    })

    /* 
    * #overlay is the transparent element 
    * that will sit over the top of #object
    */
    $("#overlay").on("mouseenter", function(){
        // divs you want to hide/show
        $('#object').show();
        $('#overlay').hide();
    })
});
```

see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/si_jsfiddle/CvkyE/

This is a good option because mouseenter and mouseleave aren't affected by objects on top of them especially with out the tag object parameter set in the on() method, this is also why they're great for div containers with links on top etc...

Answer (score 2):

Could this be useful? [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

[fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/pmxNR/)

Ex:

```
function handler(ev) {
  var $target = $(ev.target);
  if( $target.is("#element") ) {
   alert('Here am I !');
  }
}
$("#element").hover(handler);
```

And here is a slight modification **to remove element**

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/pmxNR/2/)

```
function handler(ev) {
  var $target = $(ev.target);
  if( $target.is("#element") ) {
         $target.remove();
  }
}
$("#element").mouseleave(handler);
```

Comment: I'm not sure. I have to go to work now so I'll check it out later. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ here is the jquery function. It has a good example too.

Comment: he stated that he cannot use `mouseenter` which is a wrapper for `mouseover`

Comment: I need to check the state of the mouse, not event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input etc.... onmouseover="if (condition){calltoafunction();"}>
```

On Javascript:If the Cursor is over an Item then if condition work.